# Can a US Green Card holder travel to the Schengen area without a visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, filipino-citizens, us-residents

I'm a US green card holder and a permanent resident here in the US however I have a Philippine passport and am a citizen from that country. Do I need a Schengen Visa to travel to France for a few weeks, just a trip?

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter if you have a green card or not, what matters is your nationality. [This list](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/who-needs-schengen-visa/) says Philippine nationals need a visa.

You can use the green card to prove ties to your home country though!

A USA residence permit (green card) can only exempt you from having to get a transit visa. This won't matter for you as you are visiting and not transferring and Philippine citizens don't need a transfer visa anyway.

Comment: Does this apply to **ground** transit too or only to airport?

Comment: @Suncatcher airport only. See https://visaguide.world/europe/schengen-visa/transit/